# react-native : won't download package when running on device

Tags: react-native

I have react native project and it works fine on both simulator and device.

But I notice that when I try to run my project(on device) while my computer is turned off, I can't run the project.

I works fine when my computer is powered on.

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: generate an apk to be able to run it offline

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli thanks for the reply. But I don't know about apk could you guide me how to do it?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android
// assuming your're building for android,

Comment: @HendEl-Sahli thank you very much actually I was using iOS. I don't see apk document for ios in https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is not working because of bundle is not working in an offline state (node server is closed).

**Android Build(apk)**

Now Create offline js bundle with this following command.

```
  react-native bundle --platform android 
--dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output
 android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle 
--assets-dest android/app/src/main/res/
```

Now run this command to create offline resource files and others

```
cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease
```

Open ~/android folder using Android Studio and you have your stand alone android application.

**IOS Build(IPA)**

Before creating bundle please check AppDelegate.m file For IPA building we need to static bundle which worked on offline mode

```
  #if DEBUG

    jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
    #else

    jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
    #endif
```

Creating an Offline Bundle

```
react-native bundle --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --platform ios
```

Now we open Xcode and perform the following actions

1    Product -> Clean

2    Product -> Archive

Then you have to go for **Product -> Archive** in Xcode and follow the steps based on your desired release

Comment: Hello @kirimi Please check I have updated my answer added IPA generation process